# Uploading a video to S3 with swift The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)"

Tags: swift, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a video file to Amazon S3
I constantly get an error 260:

> Error in uploading the video: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 260.)

I read somewhere that amazon does not support asset library - is it true? and if so what do you suggest
Thanks Eran

func saveVideoToS3 () {

```
    var uploadRequest: AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()

    uploadRequest.bucket = "BucketName"
    uploadRequest.key = "KeyText"

    //Move video file to the application folder so it can be read

    var savedVideoURLToBeUsed =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ThisIsTheVideoIWantToUse") as! String
    println("Video saved in Store: \(savedVideoURLToBeUsed)")

    var url: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savedVideoURLToBeUsed)!

    uploadRequest.body = url
    //uploadRequest.body = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file:///\(url)")

    println("URL: \(url)")

    let transferManager: AWSS3TransferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()


    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (AWSTask) -> AnyObject! in

        //Handle errors
        if AWSTask.error != nil {

            println("Error in uploading the video: \(AWSTask.error)")

            if AWSTask.error.code == 1001 {

                self.saveVideoToS3()
            }
        // Retrive information important for later downloading
        } else {
            println("Video upload successful..")
            var uploadResult: AnyObject! = AWSTask.result
            println("Upload result: \(uploadResult)")

            //Delete file from the application folder

        }
        return nil

    })


}
```

Comment: Tried to change file location. Still did not work:  var url: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savedVideoURLToBeUsed)!
                
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        
        let newNSURL: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/PM.MOV")!

        fileManager.copyItemAtURL(url, toURL: newNSURL, error: nil)

        uploadRequest.body = newNSURL

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa error 260 is a `NSFileReadNoSuchFileError`, meaning the path you specified is not valid (file is just not where you say it is), so it probably has nothing with S3 itself. There are three things why this is happening that come to my mind:

- you did not use `.synchronize()` when saving the key to user settings
- your file URL contains invalid characters
- you did not write the file into filesystem properly

**iOS8 Breaking change**

Also please note that as of iOS8, due to changes how application work with their assigned sandboxes, you can't save absolute URL to file because next time you open application, it will be different.

> Beginning in iOS 8, the Documents and Library directories are no
>   longer siblings of your application's bundle.

I am using two quick convenience functions that I wrote to get file from cache directory:

```
func cachePathWithFileName(fileName : String) -> String {

    let cacheDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    return cacheDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
}
```

and documents directory:

```
func documentsPathWithFileName(fileName : String) -> String {

    let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    return documentsDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
}
```

Hopefully some of this tips help!

Comment: Thanks. I found out that if you save the file prior to performing the S3 upload the error is gone... Thus I automatically save the file within the code. Still there seems to be some bugs in the connection to S3 itself.